# Simulate button click with jQuery if URL contains string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im wondering if theres a way to simulate a button click with jQuery when my url contains a string?

When you visit my page an anchor is passed through the url, only I cant take the user straight to this anchor as it uses the scrollpath plugin, so i want to simulate a navigation link being clicked...

Is this possible?

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('group') > -1) {
    $('nav ul li a.group-btn').click();
};
```

Comment: Yes it is...did you try it?

Comment: this should work if you wait for all you markup and script to be loaded : $(document).ready(...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct it is possible to explicitly call click for a button

```
$("#other").click(function() {
   $("#target").click();
});
```

refer http://api.jquery.com/click/

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7pSs/)

Comment: It's worth nothing, this is an `input`, not an `anchor`, as suggested in the question.

Comment: It wont make much difference, main motive was to show that we can simulate click  event.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can a simulate click on an anchor in the sense of a re-direct; if you can I know it isn't widely supported as it isn't possible on the iPad. You could however change the `window.location` in a similar fashion. You'll also want to keep in mind whether there are additional `click` events bound to the anchor which you may want to trigger manually.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('group') > -1) {
    window.location = $('nav ul li a.group-btn').attr('href');
};
```

### Hacky option

***Disclaimer... this is not tested in any browser apart from Chrome.***

After talking with [nbrookes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803925/nbrooks) it was discovered that you *can* trigger and simulate a click event, but not by clicking the link, but by clicking an image within the anchor. This is causing the event to bubble up, and actually trigger a click event as if a user had clicked it.

**[jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cjafW/14/show/light/) ([code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cjafW/14/))**

```
$(function() {
    // clicking this will trigger the click, but no re-direct
    $('#trigger').click(function() {
       $('#google').click(); 
    });

    // clicking this will actually re-direct... who knew!
    $('#hack').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<img />').appendTo($('#google')).click();
    });

    $('a').click(function() {
       $('#click-log').append('<li>#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' clicked</li>'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click

Comment: @nbrookes Yes, the `click()` method will trigger any `click` events bound to the object. Sadly this won't simulate a page redirect.

Comment: No it doesn't. http://fiddle.jshell.net/GeekyEggo/cjafW/show/light/

Comment: oops, you're right. The situation I was thinking of is when you call `click` on something inside a link, which will then cause the browser to follow the link. It's strange that it isn't consistent about that, but I guess it is what it is. http://jsfiddle.net/n8wL8/

Comment: Interesting find though; I didn't realise triggering the `click` on the image bubbled to the anchor and simulated a re-direct. Good to know! :)

Answer (score 0):

Click event will not do the navigation as you click on anchor.

See your solution in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZnNb/) example.

```
<div id='srcLinks'>
<a href='#group'>Success</a>
<a href='#'>Failure</a>
</div>

<a id='tgtLink' href='http://google.com' target='_blank'>target link</a>
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $('#srcLinks a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent default navigation using the href of the link
        if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('group') > -1)
        {
            // If you want to open the link in new tab
            window.open($('#tgtLink').attr('href'));
            // If you want to open the link in same window
            window.location = $('#tgtLink').attr('href');
        }
    });
});
```